# How to use a custom font with Windows Universal app?

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Like for my other windows phone 8 projects I wanted to use a custom font. But with the new Universal app architecture I struggle to put that in place.

I have created a "Fonts" folder in the shared project, I added the fonts files with the property Build Action to "Content".

I also created a "Themes" folder in the shared project and I added a ResourceDictionnary to it ("Generic.xaml").

I added a FontFamily resource :

```
<FontFamily x:Key="RexBoldFontFamily">/Fonts/Rex Bold.otf#Rex Bold</FontFamily>
```

I referenced it in the App.xaml like that:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="true" />

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

In my MainPage.xaml on my Windows Phone project I tried to use it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HelloWorld}" Foreground="{ThemeResource RedBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource RexBoldFontFamily}" FontSize="22"/>
```

I know for sure that this is the name of the font because this works on one of my windows phone app. And all of this is well wired because it works well with a color resource.

Any one succeded to share the font and use it,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're doing it all right, except for the font name (part after the '#'). It seems to be Rex, not Rex Bold.

```
<FontFamily x:Key="RexBoldFontFamily">/Fonts/Rex Bold.otf#Rex</FontFamily>
```

Comment: I'm at work right now but as soon I came home I will check that. But I doubt that because I used "#Rex Bold" in another project (WP8 Silverlight) and it works fine.

Comment: So it worked, but I still doesn't understand why it's different in Windows Phone 8 Silverlight:\

Comment: It's important to understand that the this part #Rex is the preferred family for the font. For some font's it can be real tough to get it right. If in doubt you can always look at this blogpost: http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/01/04/a-complete-guide-to-working-with-custom-fonts-in-your-windows-and-windows-phone-app

Comment: This blog saved my life. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use this code in ur xaml

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtblk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Assets/filename.ttf#Font Name"/>
```