# External Font Not Loading in Xaml

Tags: xaml, fonts, windows-phone-8.1

i tried to load a downloaded font in windows phone app.
 i installed  the font in pc.
i tried following

```
<TextBlock Width="237" Text="About"  FontSize="36" Height="46" LineHeight="8"
FontFamily="{StaticResource nokia}"/>            

<TextBlock Width="237"  Text="About"  
FontFamily="/font/nokia.ttf#Nokia Cellphone"  FontSize="36" Height="46"  LineHeight="8"/>
```

why external font is not loading

Comment: Are you sure Nokia Cellphone is the proper name? Have you tried /font/nokia.ttf#Nokia? Is the build action set to content?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23971356/2681948) and its answer will help a little.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the font is installed on the PC or not.

For a font to work inside your app you'll need a few things. 
You'll have to set the build action to 'Content' and output to directory set to: 'Copy if newer'.

And then the hardest part - Getting the preferred family right. I usually advocate using a tool for it, because the Windows Font viewer does not always show the right one.
'dp font viewer' is the one I usually use.

For a complete guide on implementing custom fonts, you could have a look here: http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/01/04/a-complete-guide-to-working-with-custom-fonts-in-your-windows-and-windows-phone-app