# Cannot get fonts to work in Windows Phone 8.1 project

Tags: fonts, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Currently working on bringing my old WP7 Silverlight app to WP8.1 RT.

I am really struggling to change the font in WP8.1. I have tried following the article on this site but I cannot get it to work:
http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/01/04/a-complete-guide-to-working-with-custom-fonts-in-your-windows-and-windows-phone-app

So far I have tried using the different Segoe UI Fonts but in Blend/Visual Studio 2013 or the app when I run it the font always stays the same. (Universal System font)

I have tried adding the other Segoe UI fonts in a folder called fonts in my project and then tried referencing those, but again I run into the same problem.

I have also tried adding the font called 'Lane' to my project and then referencing it. I again have used the method set out in the article that I linked to.

My XAML is:

```
<TextBlock Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0600" FontSize="73.333" FontFamily="ms-appx:///Fonts/LANENAR.ttf#Lane - Narrow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,3,5,3" Height="76"/>
```

Any help is very much appreciated, I am sure that there is a very simple solution to my problem and I am being stupid.

Comment: Is the font file's build action set to "Content"? Also, I'm not writing the `ms-appx:///` part, but I guess that's not the problem. And are you sure the font's name is `Lane - Narrow`?

Comment: Try using it like this, making sure that the font name is right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971356/how-to-use-a-custom-font-with-windows-universal-app/23975159#23975159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the build action to content and use the right name of the font

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/Fonts/lanenar.ttf#Lane" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0600" FontSize="73.333"  />
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I got it working with the Lane font, but what would you do if you wanted say Segoe WP Light, been trying with the Segoe UI and Segoe WP fonts but cant seem to get those to work.