# Xamarin Forms - UWP Fonts

Tags: fonts, xamarin.forms, uwp

I come here today, one more time about the same question... I can't find, in spit of every either post or question I could see, or answer I got about it..

**How does work custom fonts with UWP?**

I red the tutorial and honestly, I think I know it as a child who knows is *** poem !

I tried so much but nothing work...

```
font = "/Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto Light";
font = @"\Assets\Fonts\Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto Light";
font = "./Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto Light";
font = @".\Assets\Fonts\Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto Light";
font = "/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto Light";
font = @"\Fonts\Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto Light";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a custom font with Windows Universal app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971356/how-to-use-a-custom-font-with-windows-universal-app)

Comment: I think so, I'll give it a try, thank ! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One important thing here is, for [some weight of font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font), e.g. Light/Bold etc, we don't use the full font name followed # symbol

For example, if we need to set **Roboto Light** as Font, use **Roboto** instead.

```
/Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto" Text="This is a test: Roboto Light FontSize: 10" FontSize="10" />
```

Comment: Omg, perfect ! It does finaly works... why doesn't xamarin put that note on the official Font tutorial? Thank !

Comment: I'm happy to finaly found your answer, I'm about 4-5 asked questions over stackoverflow and the xamarin.forums ..